# Fortrabbit git pull issue - Could not get lock on repository

Tags: git, fortrabbit

I'm trying to pull from a git repository on a Fortrabbit app but getting the following error:

> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c
>   credential.helper=sourcetree fetch origin
>
> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c
>   credential.helper=sourcetree pull origin master
>
> A B O R T E D
>
> !! Could not get lock on repository; probably deployment in
>   progress.
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists. Completed with errors, see above

---

There's no deployment still in progress but the message started appearing after a (successful) deployment was made to the app from another laptop. Credentials are valid for both machines on the Fortrabbit dashboard for this app.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to clear this issue? Thanks!